# Accesing attributes in the joining table with has_many through

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations, has-many

I have a many2many relationship with a has_many through association:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :trips_users
  has_many :trips, through: :trips_users
end

class Trip < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :trips_users
  has_many :users, through: :trips_users
end

class TripsUser < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :trip
end
```

The joining table trips_user contains a column named 'pending' which id like get when I ask for a list of trips of a user.

So in my controller I need to get all trips a user has, but also adding the 'pending' column.

I was trying

> current_user.trips.includes(:trips_users)

that will be done by this select statement:

> SELECT `trips`.* FROM `trips` INNER JOIN `trips_users` ON `trips`.`id`
>   = `trips_users`.`trip_id` WHERE `trips_users`.`user_id` = 3

which is missing the information in the trips_users table that I want.

The desired sql would be:

> SELECT trips.*, trips_users.* FROM trips INNER JOIN trips_usersON trips.id =
>   trips_users.trip_id WHERE trips_users.user_id = 3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This finally worked:

```
current_user.trips.select('trips_users.*, trips.*')
```

Overriding the select part of the SQL.

Not very pretty in my opinion thou, I shouldn't be messing with tables and queries but models, specially in such a common case of a m2m association with extra data in the middle.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to use `joins` rather than includes for this...  See the following Rails Guide:

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#joining-tables

Essentially you'd do something like this:

```
current_user.trips.joins(:trips_users)
```

The `includes` method is used for eager loading, while `joins` actually performs the table join.

Comment: It didn't work, it actually returns same object twice with no data from the joining table.

Answer (score 0):

You could also try:

```
trips_users = current_user.trips_users.includes(:trip)
trips_users.first.pending?
trips_users.first.trip
```

Which should give you the trips_users records for that user but also eager loading the trips so that accessing them wouldn't hit the database again.

Comment: It doesn't work and I dont understand what is it doing. It gives me this SQL => 

SELECT `trips_users`.* FROM `trips_users` WHERE `trips_users`.`user_id` = 3 ORDER BY `trips_users`.`[:user_id, :trip_id]` ASC LIMIT 1

Comment: > It doesn't work
What error did it give?

I think maybe it should have been .includes(:trip)